# Contradictory results when training Keras Adversarial Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[image: training history]

The model is set up to train off of 1400 samples in the form of a time series 4000 steps long of 3 features. I am trying to make a synthetic time series with the model. I'm using Tensorflow 2.2.0 with Python 3.6 in an up to date conda environment in a Jupyter notebook.

By reputation, GANs are notoriously hard to train. One thing that makes me suspect the error is due to my code, rather than a model instability, is that GANs are zero-sum gain. In the above image we see both the Discriminator and Generator race toward 100% accuracy. I was expecting, if the model was properly set up, that they would have an inverse relationship, and then one could proceed to tweak the hyperparameters.

If the discriminator is too strong, how to then explain the generator's behaviour? Do I have the training flags set correctly? I'm using `sigmoid` on the Discriminator's output which makes sense as it's outputting a probability. Trying other activations on the Generator leads to the same results, and so I have settled on 'sigmoid' but maybe someone has a better recommendation?

```
BATCH_SIZE = 24

# Compile the model
g = build_generator()
d = build_discriminator()

d.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.0005), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

model_input = Input(shape=(750,), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, name='model_input')
model_output = d(g(model_input))
GAN = Model(model_input, model_output)

GAN.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.0004), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])

def train_discriminator():

    valid = np.ones((BATCH_SIZE,1))
    fake = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE,1))
    
    # Samples for the batch of training
    idx = tf.random.uniform((1,BATCH_SIZE), minval=0, maxval=training_data.shape[0], dtype=tf.dtypes.int32,)
    samples = training_data[idx]

    # Genorate Synthetic Data to Test
    noise = tf.random.normal((BATCH_SIZE,750,), 0, 1, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
    new_traces = g.predict(noise)

    d.trainable = True
    d_loss_real, d_acc_real = d.train_on_batch(samples, valid)
    d_loss_fake, d_acc_fake = d.train_on_batch(new_traces, fake)
    d_loss =  0.5 * (d_loss_real + d_loss_fake)
    d_acc = 0.5 * (d_acc_real + d_acc_fake)

    return [d_loss, d_loss_real, d_loss_fake, d_acc, d_acc_real, d_acc_fake]

def train_generator():
    d.trainable = False
    noise = tf.random.normal((BATCH_SIZE,750,), 0, 1, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
    valid = np.ones((BATCH_SIZE,1))
    g_loss, g_acc = GAN.train_on_batch(noise, valid)
    return [g_loss, g_acc]

def train(epochs):
    # Main Training Loop
    start = time.time()

    epoch = 1

    d_losses = []
    g_losses = []

    for year in range(epochs):

        d_training = train_discriminator()
        g_training = train_generator()

        print ("%d [D loss: (%.3f)(R %.3f, F %.3f)] [D acc: (%.3f)(%.3f, %.3f)] [G loss: %.3f] [G acc: %.3f]" % (epoch, d_training[0], d_training[1], d_training[2], d_training[3], d_training[4], d_training[5], g_training[0], g_training[1]))

        d_losses.append(d_training)
        g_losses.append(g_training)

        epoch += 1
    
    adjusted = round( (time.time()-start)/60, 2 )
    print(f"\nCompleted {epoch} epochs in {adjusted} min")

    return [d_losses, g_losses]
```

**Update 2020-07-19**

[image]

After updating the model with several suggestions things are looking a bit more classically volatile. About is after 500 epochs trained with 256 samples per batch.

I've updated both optimizers to Keras `Adam` and gave the Generator a higher learning rate than the Discriminator in addition to training the Generator twice for every one batch training of the Discriminator. Label smoothing also seems to have had a significant effect, and I suspect is the cause of a lot of the instability, but at least it seems to have been enough to show some convergence in the synthetic data even though the history of the training model is all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using LeakyReLU, they seem to work better in both generator and discriminator.
2. Consider using different batch size for generator and discriminator. And try to use batch sizes that are the power of 2.
3. Use label smoothing. You can find it in the binary crossentropy function.
4. Use SGD for discriminator and Adam for generator or just use Adam for both. SGD is also very hard to train, you need to have a good training schedule for it to work in your favour.
5. Also, train discriminator and generator for different amount of epochs. Like train discriminator for 1 epoch and then, generator for 5.

Comment: In regards to #3, I chose uniform bc I assumed one wanted to have all the samples in the training data to be used approximately an equal number of times. This would not be the case with a Gaussian (or Normal) distribution if I am understanding your suggestion correctly?

Comment: Did changing it help or harm? Sampling data using uniform is fine. But, generation should be from Gaussian.